# Validator not working in any browser even using IE

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, c#-4.0

I create textbox for user to choose the date and set the requiredfieldvalidator.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="StartDate" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
    ValidationGroup="Search" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" 
    ToolTip="*Fill START Date!">*Fill START Date!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="EndDate" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
    ValidationGroup="Search" Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="*Fill END Date!">*Fill END  Date!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Label ID="DateFilter" runat="server" 
    Text="Filter by Date from :" style="font-family: 'Arial Narrow'" 
    AssociatedControlID="StartDate"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('CalendarPopup.aspx?textbox=StartDate','cal','width=220,height=205,left=270,top=180')"><img id="Img1" 
    src="calendar-icon.gif"  border="0" runat="server" alt="calendar" 
    style="height: 23px" align="bottom"></a>

 <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="to" Font-Names="Arial Narrow" 
     AssociatedControlID="EndDate"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('CalendarPopup.aspx?textbox=EndDate','cal','width=220,height=205,left=270,top=180')"><img id="Img2" 
    src="calendar-icon.gif" border="0" runat="server" alt="calendar" 
    style="height: 23px" dir="ltr"></a>&nbsp;
<asp:Button 
    ID="Search" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Names="Arial Narrow" 
    ForeColor="White" Text="SEARCH" Width="73px" onclick="Search_Click" />
```

Then, I need to compare the first date must be less than second date using Compare Validator.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToCompare="EndDate" ControlToValidate="StartDate" 
    ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" Type="Date" 
    ValidationGroup="Search" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True">*First date must be less than or equal to Second 
date!</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Both validator are not working. Anyone kindly please help. Thanks..:)
Siti

Comment: By "not working" do you mean you are getting an error or the data is being submitted as valid even when invalid?

Comment: Not working means the error message does not display or nothing happen.

Comment: Give my answer below a shot. Your validation logic is incorrect if StartDate needs to happen before EndDate.

Comment: I already change it but still no error message display..

Comment: Check the answer again, I overlooked something previously.

Comment: Do you have EnableEventValidation property on your page set to false? Are there any other validators that are working?

Comment: She just forgot to add the ValidationGroup to the button per my answer below.

Comment: It should be, but I'm not the OP. @Siti did you try the update I posted?

Comment: Dear Lawrence Johnson, yes its working for 1st validator - RequiredValidator but the CompareValidator still not working. I already change the operator = LessThan. Anything that I am still missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, I didn't see it before, but you need to have the button be a part of the same validation group as your validators. Try this:

```
<asp:Button ValidationGroup="Search"
    ID="Search" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Names="Arial Narrow" 
    ForeColor="White" Text="SEARCH" Width="73px" onclick="Search_Click" />
```

Oh, and I'm pretty sure you need the other logic operator I mentioned before because the ControlToValidate is the primary value that gets evaluated against ControlToCompare so ControlToValidate is LessThan ControlToCompare = StartDate is LessThan EndDate:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server"
    ControlToCompare="EndDate" ControlToValidate="StartDate" 
    ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" Operator="LessThan" Type="Date" 
    ValidationGroup="Search" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True">*First date must be less than or equal to Second date!</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Since you are having problems, I have checked the code in its entirety and this works exactly as it shoul. Copy and paste this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="StartDate" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
ValidationGroup="Search" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" 
ToolTip="*Fill START Date!">*Fill START Date!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="EndDate" ErrorMessage="*Fill END Date!" 
ValidationGroup="Search" Display="Dynamic" ToolTip="*Fill END Date!" />

<asp:Label ID="DateFilter" runat="server" 
Text="Filter by Date from :" style="font-family: 'Arial Narrow'" 
AssociatedControlID="StartDate"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('CalendarPopup.aspx?textbox=StartDate','cal','width=220,height=205,left=270,top=180')"><img id="Img1" 
src="calendar-icon.gif"  border="0" runat="server" alt="calendar" 
style="height: 23px" align="bottom"></a>

<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="to" Font-Names="Arial Narrow" 
AssociatedControlID="EndDate"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('CalendarPopup.aspx?textbox=EndDate','cal','width=220,height=205,left=270,top=180')"><img id="Img2" src="calendar-icon.gif" border="0" runat="server" alt="calendar" style="height: 23px" dir="ltr"></a>&nbsp;
<asp:Button ValidationGroup="Search"
ID="Search" runat="server" BackColor="Black" Font-Names="Arial Narrow" 
ForeColor="White" Text="SEARCH" Width="73px" onclick="Search_Click" />

<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server"
ControlToCompare="EndDate" ControlToValidate="StartDate" 
ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" Operator="LessThan" Type="Date" 
ValidationGroup="Search" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True">*First date must be less than or equal to Second date!</asp:CompareValidator>
```

~

Comment: No Error Message display. Nothing happen.

Comment: Try the update above. I didn't see that you were using validation groups. Whatever event triggers validation needs to be assigned to the validation group of the members you wish to be validated.

Comment: Thank you, the RequiredFieldValidation working now but the CompareValidator still not working. I already change the Operator = LessThan. Any ideas?.Thanks..:)

Comment: I took all of your code and made the modifications indicated and it works for me. Try copying and pasting the code above to see if that works for you.